# Is "because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer" a valid close vote reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I just noticed someone voting to close a post with:

> I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary
> material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and
> working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Whilst it is certainly true that this information could be obtained from a basic book, I'm unsure as to whether it is a valid reason to close a post?

I thought the "rule" was questions can be very elementary as long as they aren't duplicates. It seems to me it might be better to downvote, not vote to close.

Comment: Whether a question can be answered easily isn't a reason to VTC, it's reason to downvote. Saying that, if it *is* a very basic question, then a duplicate is likely to exist and then you could VTC as a duplicate. If there isn't a duplicate though, and the question content is on topic (and hopefully well asked) then it's perfectly reasonable to be on the site. [so] aims to be a repository of knowledge, and that will include both simple and complex questions.

Comment: But also note that indications for close-votes and down-votes are different, and while it is incorrect to close a question for the reason stated above, it *may* be OK to down-vote the question if the questioner does not appear to demonstrate adequate effort on their part. And this makes sense to me -- it is great for the site to have detailed canonical Q&A for basic concepts, but conversely, I don't think we want a poster to be encouraged to repeatedly ask most basic questions in place of using appropriate tutorials.

Comment: If the OP could not be bothered to run through a basic tuition site, why would anyone else wast...spend their own time on searching for dupes?  Such questions are often homework anyway, and I won't waste a us on them:(

Comment: @MartinJames that's fine, nobody is asking you to spend time on them :) I was just curious as to whether **closing** them is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I often wonder whether it is harder on the ego to have a question closed or completely ghosted.

Comment: The "I won't, and don't think anyone else should, waste time with this question" button is shaped like a downward-facing triangle, @Martin. Don't confuse it with the close link.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. That's an invalid close reason.

I would recommend raising a moderator flag on the question (not the comment, as comment flags are ill-suited for things requiring action beyond editing/deleting the comment), both so that we can correct the invalid closure *and* so that we can inform the user(s) who voted to close for that reason that this is not a valid close reason.

Comment: Let me clarify: Absolutely, categorically NO, it's never correct to close a question because the answer can be found outside of Stack Overflow. We never close questions because they are too easy, unless they are duplicates of existing questions.

Comment: @Dharman By "we" you imply diamond moderators I would say, not the royal we. Because we do close questions for being too easy, as duplicates.

Comment: @Gimby I added clause for duplicates, is my comment clearer now?

Comment: @Gimby Being a dupe is not equivalent to a question being "too easy". Plenty of extremely hard questions are duplicates, and sometimes even *seeing* the fact that they're duplicates is extremely hard and requires domain-specific knowledge. I simply don't buy the equivalence you're implying between simplicity and duplicate. There's incidental overlap (in the sense that very basic questions are likely to have been answered already on a site that is over a decade old), but nothing more. Besides, new technologies come about all the time, where basic questions about them *haven't* been answered.

Answer (score 15):

There are some questions that are so *broad in scope* that turning to a textbook, course or similar is more appropriate to get the needed information in sufficient depth. That does not make the question off-topic because the information is found elsewhere; what makes such a question off-topic is that it *needs more focus*.

By itself, it is perfectly fine for a question to ask about information that is available outside of Stack Overflow already.

Comment: I'm pretty sure almost all information on SO is available outside of it. Else how are users supposed to even know what to answer? So, closing because information can be found elsewhere is indeed not correct, otherwise we have to close every single question.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm decently sure that a sizeable amount of information on SO is synthesised from personal knowledge and experience. That information could be *learned* outside of SO but it is not available per se. Where the line between these types of information goes I don't know, but it's certainly helpful that we don't *have* to know – because it doesn't matter.